# Google-plus sign in With AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-plus

I am trying to implement google+ signin using https://github.com/sirkitree/angular-directive.g-signin , it is very simple to implement as explained in this module but i am not getting it worked.

below is the js fiddle for the src.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vJDnc/)

```
<div ng-app="directive.g+signin">
          <g+signin clientid="620125449078"></g+signin>
          <p>This is a Google Plus sign-in button</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: and now?: http://jsfiddle.net/vJDnc/1/

Comment: @Cherniv thanx.. but what was the problem, both are looking same.

Comment: For people who are wondering, the inclusion of the dependancies were switched order (angular first, then g-sigin).

Answer (score 2):

You have to use Google's API console to create *YOUR OWN* client ID which pairs with the domain serving the login button.

Please read the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/).